# doxygen page expire time

Tags: html, .htaccess, doxygen

When I regenerate the documentation with doxygen (1.8.7) and upload it to the webserver, I always get re-served the same pages as before the upload.

I've tried Ctrl-F5 (FireFox), I've also tried putting the following meta in src/header.html and recompiling doxygen:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
```

I've also tried using the .htaccess file to control the cache. Unfortunately, I always get served stale html pages.

What am I missing to totally deactivate the cache for doxygen generated html?

Comment: sounds more like a problem with the webserver. Are you sure the updated pages are on the webserver? Try restarting the webserver if you can, too.

Comment: Server is Apache/2.2.3. I'm not root on this machine, and can't restart it. I could ask an admin to restart it, but will that be the permanent fix?

Comment: Are your new files definitely on the webserver? Have they definitely overwritten the old files? Are you sure the old files are not being served from a different directory? Does the server have caching and how is it handled? Restarting the server is using a big hammer to solve a small problem and will probably work, but it may not reveal what your actual problem is and you would have to do it again next time you regenerated the docs.